# levenshtein shows all records if column data is null?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with column tags and it has all **NULL** values. It returns all records when I search anything. But it works with other columns with **not null values**. I used the query like this.

```
if($searchText!=""){

    $lev=(strlen($searchText));
    $this->db->select("*,MATCH(tags) against('$searchText' IN BOOLEAN MODE)as score",FALSE); 
    $this->db->where('levenshtein(tags, "'. $searchText.'") < '.$lev,FALSE, FALSE);
    $this->db->order_by("score","desc");
    }
```

Is it so that levenshtien shows all records for null data?

Comment: depends how levenhstein is implemented, mysql don't have built in levenhstein

Comment: I am using levenshtien function from http://openquery.com.au/blog/levenshtein-mysql-stored-function